# getRedirectResult returning null

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

This code returns null:

```
firebase.auth().getRedirectResult().then((result) => {
  let user = result.user;
  console.log(user);
}).catch((error) => {
  console.log(error);
});
```

But using a setTimeout before, the code works:

```
setTimeout(() => {
  firebase.auth().getRedirectResult().then((result) => {
    let user = result.user;
    console.log(user);
  }).catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
  });
}, 3000);
```

Note: I'm using ReactJS

Answer (score 1):

This happens when there is no redirect result. This will only get populated when you are returning from a successful `signInWithRedirect` operation.